# How to auto-refresh a JTable bound to Mysql database after insert using NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I'm working on a project in `NetBeans`.

I have a `Jtable` which i bound to my database and there is a form that I use to insert data.

I want the records in the table to be refreshed with each insert.

How can I do that?

Comment: you can clear table and reload data.or you can check is insert successful,if it's successful you can add it to a row  without reloading all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should simply select the table and go to the navigator window. Under "Other Components" there is the list that was created after the binding and contains the table records (you should know its name). Right click on the list > Properties > check "observable".

Answer (score 1):

> I want the records in the table to be refreshed with each insert.

Then your "insert" logic need to do two things:

1. insert the data into the database
2. insert the data into the JTable. This is done by using the `addRow(...)` method of the `DefaultTableModel`. You get the data from the form, create a Vector to contain the data for each column then you add the Vector to the model.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code:

if you want update the table on button click or on event of any component
you have to put the code in the event

- the list generated should be Observable checked

code

```
udetailsList.clear();
udetailsList.addAll(udetailsQuery.getResultList());
```